# Unable to start my application after upgrading Spring jars

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-security

I have updated the following spring dependencies in my project `pom.xml`

From:

```
<spring.version>5.3.6</spring.version>
  <spring.security.version>5.4.4</spring.security.version>
<spring.boot.version>2.3.10.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
```

To:

```
<spring.version>5.3.8</spring.version>
  <spring.security.version>5.5.1</spring.security.version
<spring.boot.version>2.5.2</spring.boot.version>
```

I was able to build my project successfully whereas, when I tried to start my application, I see the following error and my application fails to start at all.

Can any one help me with the resolution.

```
Caused by: org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException: warning can't determine superclass of missing type org.springframework.boot.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationExcludeFilter$$Lambda$819.0x000000080096f440
 [Xlint:cantFindType]   
at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ExceptionBasedMessageHandler.handleMessage(ReflectionWorld.java:217) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar!/:?]
at org.aspectj.weaver.Lint$Kind.signal(Lint.java:339) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar!/:1.9.7]    
at org.aspectj.weaver.MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.raiseCantFindType(MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.java:237) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar!/:1.9.7]
at org.aspectj.weaver.MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.getSuperclass(MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.java:98) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar!/:1.9.7]
at org.aspectj.weaver.JoinPointSignatureIterator.addSignaturesUpToFirstDefiningMember(JoinPointSignatureIterator.java:95) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar!/:1.9.7]
at org.aspectj.weaver.JoinPointSignatureIterator.<init>(JoinPointSignatureIterator.java:49) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar!/:1.9.7]
at org.aspectj.weaver.MemberImpl.getJoinPointSignatures(MemberImpl.java:515) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar!/:1.9.7]
at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.SignaturePattern.matches(SignaturePattern.java:316) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar!/:?]
at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.KindedPointcut.matchInternal(KindedPointcut.java:202) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar!/:?]
at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:137) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar!/:?]
at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.getShadowMatch(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:319) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar!/:?]
at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.matchesExecution(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:129) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar!/:?]
at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.matchesMethodExecution(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:110) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar!/:?]
at org.springframework.security.config.method.ProtectPointcutPostProcessor.attemptMatch(ProtectPointcutPostProcessor.java:148) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
at org.springframework.security.config.method.ProtectPointcutPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ProtectPointcutPostProcessor.java:125) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
... 23 more
```

Comment: I would assume there is a mismatch in the configured dependencies. Check your `pom.xml` for manual version overrides.

Comment: this is a very weird error :( , I did a quick double check to make sure you are using correct dependency versions, and it seems like you are, so since it is related to bean validation, what are you using for it? javax.validation or spring-boot-starter-validation?

Comment: If you are using spring boot you should never defined versions for spring-security or spring yourself. Use the versions which are handled by spring boot....this looks like the issue here...

Comment: @khmarbaise you might be right, but I do not agree with your comment, you need to have spring security as it does not come with default starter. The issue is probably in a dependency.

Comment: Simply wrong because the spring-boot-dependencies contains exactly an entry for spring-security.... See https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.5.2/pom

Comment: @thechaoticpanda You don't have to set version for Spring an Spring Security, but you have to add the dependencies (without version element).

Answer (score 0):

### Warning!

This is **not** Production Grade solution but this may be considered as starting point for further investigation.

### Background

We have quite legacy (~10yo) application and we currently run into same issue during Spring Boot upgrade from 2.3.9 to 2.4.0 (Full stack below).

It seems to me that problem is related to three issues:

- `ProtectPointcutPostProcessor` - from spring security
- `MethodValidationPostProcessor` - which lack of disables the error
- change in Spring Boot 2.4.0 - which is described below

### Possible cause description

In Spring Boot 2.4.0 new Bean has been introduced in `EnableConfigurationPropertiesRegistrar`:

```
static void registerMethodValidationExcludeFilter(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
    if (!registry.containsBeanDefinition(METHOD_VALIDATION_EXCLUDE_FILTER_BEAN_NAME)) {
        BeanDefinition definition = BeanDefinitionBuilder
                .genericBeanDefinition(MethodValidationExcludeFilter.class,
                        () -> MethodValidationExcludeFilter.byAnnotation(ConfigurationProperties.class))
                .setRole(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE).getBeanDefinition();
        registry.registerBeanDefinition(METHOD_VALIDATION_EXCLUDE_FILTER_BEAN_NAME, definition);
    }
}
```

This bean is generated with `MethodValidationExcludeFilter.byAnnotation` as Lambda:

```
static MethodValidationExcludeFilter byAnnotation(Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType,
        SearchStrategy searchStrategy) {
    return (type) -> MergedAnnotations.from(type, SearchStrategy.SUPERCLASS).isPresent(annotationType);
}
```

Because of being Lambda it has no parent class and fails miserably on bean creation post processing.

### (Very) hacky solution

Luckily `EnableConfigurationPropertiesRegistrar.registerMethodValidationExcludeFilter` contains if statement which checks if bean has not been created. So we may create this bean manually instead:

```
@Bean("org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationPropertiesRegistrar.methodValidationExcludeFilter")
public MethodValidationExcludeFilter mockMethodValidationExcludeFilter() {​​​​​​​​
    return new MethodValidationExcludeFilter() {​​​​​​​​
        @Override
public boolean isExcluded( Class< ? > type ) {​​​​​​​​
            return MethodValidationExcludeFilter.byAnnotation( ConfigurationProperties.class).isExcluded( type );
        }​​​​​​​​
    }​​​​​​​​;
}​​​​​​​​
```

Or even as:

```
@Bean("org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationPropertiesRegistrar.methodValidationExcludeFilter")
public String mockMethodValidationExcludeFilter() {
    return "mockMethodValidationExcludeFilter";
}
```

But this seems to me as very dirty hack and not suitable for production usage.

Theoretically disabling linting error `cantFindType` could also save the day as doing it on debug has allowed application to run but

- we have not achieved proper configuration to disable it
- this seems as dirty hack as well and should be considered as last resort and not proper solution

### Logs

Full error stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationPropertiesRegistrar.methodValidationExcludeFilter' defined in class path resource [com/source/etf/common/aop/AopConfig.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException: warning can't determine superclass of missing type com.source.etf.common.aop.AopConfig$$Lambda$751.0x00000008008fec40
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:617) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at com.source.etf.EtfmApplication.main(EtfmApplication.java:56) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException: warning can't determine superclass of missing type com.source.etf.common.aop.AopConfig$$Lambda$751.0x00000008008fec40
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ExceptionBasedMessageHandler.handleMessage(ReflectionWorld.java:219) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar:na]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.Lint$Kind.signal(Lint.java:340) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar:1.9.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.raiseCantFindType(MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.java:237) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar:1.9.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.getSuperclass(MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.java:98) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar:1.9.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.JoinPointSignatureIterator.addSignaturesUpToFirstDefiningMember(JoinPointSignatureIterator.java:95) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar:1.9.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.JoinPointSignatureIterator.<init>(JoinPointSignatureIterator.java:49) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar:1.9.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.MemberImpl.getJoinPointSignatures(MemberImpl.java:515) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar:1.9.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.SignaturePattern.matches(SignaturePattern.java:319) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar:na]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.KindedPointcut.matchInternal(KindedPointcut.java:202) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar:na]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:137) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar:na]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.getShadowMatch(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:319) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar:na]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.matchesExecution(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:129) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar:na]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.matchesMethodExecution(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:110) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.method.ProtectPointcutPostProcessor.attemptMatch(ProtectPointcutPostProcessor.java:148) ~[spring-security-config-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.config.method.ProtectPointcutPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ProtectPointcutPostProcessor.java:125) ~[spring-security-config-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:429) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1780) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 16 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```